# Frequency analysis and overlay analysis

Tags: arcgis-desktop, analysis, overlay, arcgis-9.2

Am new to gis and I hope to find help here. I am working on a research that requires that I overlay conditions of drainage systems and quality of healthcare in a coastal state to get areas which have potential for increase in the incidence of malaria. Each of these two attributes of areas in the state have more than one value. For instance, under quality of health care, I have data on:presence of healthcare service, drug provision and attitude of healthcare personnel.  Under conditions of drainage system, data on: presence of open drainage, effectiveness of waste management. The data is derived from answers from respondents in a household survey. The data is in numeric form

Am using arcgis 9.2

To my question, can I use frequency analysis in gis to summarize the data and go on to overlay the two attributes

Comment: I guess we could help you better if you provide more information: what is the format of your data, which GIS platform do you use, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

[Frequency](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/index.cfm?TopicName=frequency_%28analysis%29) and [summary statistics](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/index.cfm?TopicName=Summary_Statistics_%28Analysis%29) were definitely present in version 9.2, frequency has been around since I've been using ESRI products (early 1990's). Summary Statistics offers more powerful statistic types over frequency, and can work with a basic license (ArcView) where frequency needs advanced (INFO) license.

Same with [Intersect](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/index.cfm?TopicName=Intersect_%28Analysis%29), [Identity](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/index.cfm?TopicName=Identity_%28Analysis%29) and [Union](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/index.cfm?TopicName=Union_%28Analysis%29), which do similar things - look at the pictures and decide which one is for you. An INFO license would serve you well here; if you have ArcView or ArcEdit license use [spatial join](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/index.cfm?TopicName=Spatial_Join_%28Analysis%29) to overlay.

I think you want Intersect the two datasets followed by summary statistics to tabulate the data.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if ArcGIS 9.2 support vector overlaying.
You can use **QGIS 2.2** (free opensource GIS that you can download from qgis.org). After installing, open your vector files, and then, **menu "Vector" - "Data Management Tools" - "Join attributes by location"**